# Should I switch to IIS7 URL rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm using Intelligencia url rewriting currently but have just leased an IIS 7.5 server to put my asp.net 3.5 site on.   I installed the IIS URL rewriting module and was amazed at how easy it was to create rules.  Creating rules with the Intelligencia url rewriter is complicated (at least for me).  Are there any downsides to switching?  Is there a reason for me not to move on to the Microsoft solution?   This site isn't live yet, so I have time to switch

Comment: Downsides could include introducing defects, regression testing and possible increased costs. All of which may make your Project Manager (if you have one mad) or cause a cost increase if you are on a fixed price contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used either of them. If it simplify your work, you should go with it.  IIS7 url rewriter is here to stay. Before migrating also check asp.net 4.0 's inbuilt url rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

You may also have a look at [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) software which was designed by Helicon Tech specifically for IIS7 and higher. It has [human-friendly syntax](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_rewrite.htm) and easy-to-use manager and possesses 30+ other modules to tune up your server.